# what does it means for p value = 8.780e-13

Tags: pca, p-value, spss, exploratory-data-analysis

I would like to ask if 8.780e-13 is greater than 0.05 for significance? I am not sure what is the calculation of this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The duplicate can be found as one of the top hits in searching our site for answers containing ["E-" faq](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=+%22E-%22+is%3Aanswer+faq).  For those who are aware this is *scientific notation,* the top hits in a search for answers mentioning ["E-" scientific number](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=number+%22E-%22+is%3Aanswer+scientific) are all helpful.

Answer (score 1):

8.780e-13 is a shorthand for $8.780 \times 10^{-13}$, which is thus smaller than $0.05$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation.